# Delete files older than 3 days if disk usage is over 85 percent in bash

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I'm working on a bash code which would enter the command df-h, loop through the disk usage fields and print the number using awk and if any of the disk usage reaches over 85 percent, it would find the files older than 3 days within the log path indicated in variable and remove them.

However upon trying to run the script, it constantly complains that the  command was not found on line 6.

This is the code that I'm working on

```
files =$(find /files/logs -type f -mtime +3 -name '*.log)
process =$(df-h | awk '{print $5+0}')
for i in process
 do
if $i -ge 85
then
    for k in $files
       do
       rm -rf $k
   done

fi

done;
```

Its so irritating because I feel that I'm so close to the solution and yet I still cant figure out as to whats wrong with the script that it refuses to work

Comment: It complains on the first line you show because you have spaces around the `=` assignment operator. Same with `process =...`. On the other hand you need a space between `df` and `-h`. Then, even if you fix these errors, you'll hit another wall: `for in in process` iterates only once with `i` set to the literal string `"process"`. You should probably read a `bash` quick starter to understand the basics before trying to code.

Comment: Please add a suitable shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) and then paste your script at http://www.shellcheck.net/ and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Answer (score 0):

you are searching files in /files/logs so you are probably only interested in this partition (root partition?)

- your if statement did not respect the proper syntax... should be  `if [[ x -gt y ]]; then`....
- there was no need to loop thhrough the files collected by find since you can use `-exec` directly in find (see `man find`)

```
#!/bin/bash

# find the partition that contains the log files (this example with root partition)
PARTITION="$(mount | grep "on / type" | awk '{print $1}')"

# find the percentage used of the partition
PARTITION_USAGE_PERCENT="$(df -h | grep "$PARTITION" | awk '{print $5}' | sed s/%//g)"

# if partition too full...
if [[ "$PARTITION_USAGE_PERCENT" -gt 85 ]]; then
    # run command to delete extra files
    printf "%s%s%s\n" "Disk usage is at " "$PARTITION_USAGE_PERCENT" "% deleting log files..."
    find /files/logs -type f -mtime +3 -name '*.log' -exec rm {} \;
fi
```

Comment: `[[ x > y ]]` isn't for numbers, see the result of `[[ 8 > 100 ]] && echo yes`

Comment: edited and changed to ```-gt```

Comment: @fun_times while that'd work a better approach would be to change to a numeric notation `(( x > y ))` instead.

Comment: @EdMorton can you detail why it is a better approach?

Comment: There may be other reasons too but clarity and simplicity and extensibility are some reasons, The numeric constructs exist to do numeric operations, not using `(( x > y ))` for a numeric comparison is like using `expr $i + 1` instead of `$(( i + 1 ))`. You can also write clear, simple loops like `for (( i=1; i<=10; i+=2 )); do ...` and be consistent with the rest of your code using `if (( x > y )); then`.